Show that $D(f) \subseteq \mathbb{A}_k^{n+1}$ is an affine algebraic set with coordinate ring $A[f^{-1}]$
I was trying to do the following exercise from: https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/ja/alggeoI/blatt01.pdf
Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n(k)$ be an affine algebraic set with
$D(X):=\{f\in k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]|f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=0 \forall x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in X\}$
and coordinate ring $A:=O(X)=k[X_1,\cdots,X_n]/I(X)$. Let $f\in A$ be any element. Prove that
$D(f):= \{x=(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in X|f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\not= 0\}$
is open in $X$. Show that
$D(f) \subseteq \mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k), x\mapsto (x_1,\cdots,x_n,f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^{-1})$
is again an affine algebraic set with coordinate ring given by the localisation $A[f^{-1}].$
I have no problem showing $D(f)$ is open in $X$. But I have troubles understanding the second part of the question. Is the question asking to show that the image of the map $D(f) \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k), x\mapsto (x_1,\cdots,x_n,f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^{-1})$ is an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)$? If so, let
$Y:=Im (D(f)\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k))=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n,f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^{-1})\in \mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k) | f(x_1,\cdots,x_n) \not= 0, (x_1,\cdots,x_n) \in X\}$
So we have $Y = D(f) \times \{f(x_1,\cdots,x_n)^{-1}\}$. But I don't see how this is an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)$ since it is a set of points that does not vanish on some polynomial rather than vanishing.

Your calculation of $Y$ is incorrect. It should be $Y = V(x_{n+1}f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) - 1)$.  Then it is clear that $Y$ is an affine algebraic subset of $\mathbb{A}^{n+1}(k)$.  Can you show this?

@kobe I got it now, many thanks!
